# create fliping book with images

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I want to create a application in which i required following function
create array of images in view and move like  page turning effect orientation change then same view will execute. tap on image then zoom in or zoom out image.
 double tap then upload bigger image from web-services.
on image when select part of image then open url of that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these Sample code

https://github.com/devindoty/iBooks-Flip-Animation

http://oleb.net/blog/2010/06/app-store-safe-page-curl-animations/

https://github.com/mtabini/AFKPageFlipper

Answer (score 0):

[AFKPageFlipper](https://github.com/mtabini/AFKPageFlipper) will help you with the page-flip-effect. The other questions: First, try to solve it self (zoom, ...) and if you have problem ask a new questions here.