# What are the ways to develop a Book like app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, core-animation

I have a situation here, I want to replicate an app which will look like a book for content of book I'll have a XML feed that feed will have information pertaining to contents and number of pages.

The situation is number of pages will vary every time so can you suggest me a way to show varied number of pages every time + how to apply the flip animation while user is browsing these pages.

Please enlighten me on this.

Regards
Ankit

Comment: can any body let me know why its voted negative I did the research but I had no clue on technicality of this moreover all the approaches shown in answer are for pdfs and images my question is for transition between views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[create fliping book with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593961/create-fliping-book-with-images)

I have implemented AFK Page Flipper from this list and is very easy.

Comment: I need the solution for views not for images or pdfs though I appreciate your effort

Comment: the title says, for images. But the flipper takes views as its input to flip the pages. You know, you can put anything into views(text, images, or whatever).